# Rust zero copy lifetime handling

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement a zero copy mechanism for realtime data processing in Rust.
To illustrate my issue, I prepared the following example:

```
use std::io;

pub trait Producer<T> {
    fn produce(&self) -> Result<T, ()>;
}

pub trait Consumer<T> {
    fn consume(&self, t: T);
}

pub trait Source<T> : Producer<T> {
    fn push(&self, t: T) -> io::Result<()>;
}

pub trait Sink<T> : Consumer<T> {
    fn pull(&self) -> io::Result<T>;
}

pub struct SyncSource<T> {
    pub producer: Option<Box<dyn Fn() -> T>>,
}

impl<T> SyncSource<T> {
    pub fn new() -> SyncSource<T> {
        SyncSource {
            producer: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Producer<T> for SyncSource<T> {
    fn produce(&self) -> Result<T, ()> {
        match &self.producer {
            Some(func) => Ok((*(func))()),
            None => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Source<T> for SyncSource<T> {
    fn push(&self, t: T) -> io::Result<()> {
        // do something useful
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub struct Frame<'a> {
    pub buf: &'a [u8],
}

pub struct Capture {
    buf: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Capture {
    pub fn add(&mut self, val: u8) {
        self.buf.push(val);
    }

    pub fn read(&self) -> Frame {
        Frame {
            buf: &self.buf[..],
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut capture = Capture {
        buf: Vec::new(),
    };

    let source: SyncSource<Frame> = SyncSource::new();

    // immutable borrow of 'capture'
    let frame = capture.read();

    source.push(frame);

    // mutable borrow of 'capture'
    capture.add(1); // ERROR
}
```

.. which of course yields a borrow checker error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `capture` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> src/bin/so.rs:212:5
    |
208 |     let frame = capture.read();
    |                 ------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
212 |     capture.add(1);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
213 | }
    | - immutable borrow might be used here, when `source` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `SyncSource<'_, Frame<'_>>`
```

I understand that `push(frame)` cannot have an immutable reference in the same scope where `capture.add(1)` needs the mutable reference a few lines later.

What I'm trying to achieve is for `push(frame)` to be able to do something useful with the slice (and maybe copy it into a Vec if necessary), but with the possibility not to do anything with it.

Basically I need to ensure the lifetime of `frame` ends once `push(frame)` has been called. This would then release the borrowed reference to `Capture` and the `capture.add(1)` call would succeed with a proper mutable reference being acquired.

My zero-copy requirement mandates not copying the slice into a Vec and then handing that new buffer to `push(..)`.
What am I missing here? Perhaps some explicit lifetime annotations?

Comment: I think in this case simply having `let mut owner = ...` solves the compilation error. and NLL (non-lexical-lifetimes) should be enough so that your example works as intended: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bbec1babeb74a0d4808c7088e91062b1

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally uploaded the wrong code. I updated the post with the proper example now.

Comment: What happens if you put source, sink, frame in a separate scope? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=26422be668676569c504259117d80af8

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option because I have a while .. loop in the main function which reads a frame, pushes it down the pipeline and then modifies the Capture object. Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab2bac610455a2b015cca8601943f943.

Comment: This code is very abstract, which makes it hard to fix because I don't know what fixes might be appropriate or not. I'm guessing the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355940/rust-trait-field-lifetime) didn't stick because you're not using `&'a mut self` anymore?

Comment: Can you spend some time trying to pare it down to a [mre]? For instance, I notice that `Source::link` and `Sink::link` are not used at all in the example, so you should be able to trim a lot of fluff (and about half the lifetime annotations) by getting rid of them, which helps focus on (what I suppose is) the problem at hand. (I suspect the lifetime annotations on those are inappropriate, anyway -- explicit lifetimes are *very* rarely suitable for mutual relationships. You might want `Rc`/`Arc` or some `Clone` bounds somewhere.)

Comment: Except for the link(..) methods, the example is already stripped down to the bare minimum. I can remove those if they bother you. As you already noticed, the mutual Source/Sink relationship is broken.. which is probably another issue.
In C++ I have `Source` which has a `shared_ptr<Sink>` member and the `Sink` has an observing pointer `*Source` member. How would I model this in Rust? Should the source have a Box<Sink> owning member?

EDIT: Okay, I should probably pose a separate question for the linking and mutual relationship stuff. Give me a few to update the example.

Comment: `Box` would be the equivalent of `unique_ptr`; `Arc` (or possibly `Rc`) is what you would use to replace `shared_ptr`. Not sure about the `*Source`; it depends on why you used a raw pointer. You could of course use raw pointers in Rust as well but there may be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I edited the example; is this what you're looking for?
Regarding the `*Source` raw pointer in C++, the relationship I want to model is as follows:

1) `Source` and `Sink` can exist on their own.
2) To create a pipeline, a `Sink` is linked to a `Source`. To achieve this, I want to store a reference to the `Sink` in the `Source` instance and vice versa so the Source can push its elements to the sink and the sink can pull from the source (bidirectional pipeline).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212301/discussion-between-trentcl-and-acr).

Answer (score 2):

### How to fix it

Create a new block to ensure that the immutable borrow (`source`) is dropped before `capture` is mutated:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=280447d85b6c14f58de8ae874b075d82)

```rust
let mut capture = Capture {
    buf: Vec::new(),
};

{
    let source: SyncSource<Frame> = SyncSource::new();

    // immutable borrow of 'capture'
    let frame = capture.read();

    // borrow moved into `source`
    source.push(frame);

    // `source` dropped here
}

// mutable borrow of 'capture'
capture.add(1);
```

### Why NLL doesn't help

This problem should be fixed with [non-lexical lifetimes](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html#non-lexical-lifetimes) (NLL). However, NLL don't work for types that implement the [Drop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) trait, because `Drop` is always called at the end of a value's lexical scope for backwards compatibility.

Since `SyncSource` contains a trait object (`dyn Fn() -> T`), which could potentially implement `Drop`, NLL is prevented in this case. In [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73709fb8dbdece342ec8ad439df7231d) you can see that removing the trait object fixes the error thanks to NLL.

### But I want to access both `source` and `capture` in a loop!

Then mutable and immutable borrows are *interleaved*, which means that Rust can't verify the ownership rules at compile time.

You can work around this by using [RefCell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), which ensures that the ownership rules are upheld *at runtime*. This can be  implemented like this:

```rust
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};

pub struct Frame<'a> {
    pub buf: Ref<'a, Vec<u8>>,
}

pub struct Capture {
    buf: RefCell<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Capture {
    pub fn add(&self, val: u8) {
        self.buf.borrow_mut().push(val);
    }

    pub fn read(&self) -> Frame {
        Frame {
            buf: self.buf.borrow(),
        }
    }
}
```